# Remove the line break "\n" after a "\" character in Notepad++

Tags: expression, notepad++, line-breaks

I have a CSV file that contains about 100'000 records some of which have been broken into multiple lines at a "\" character in the source data during the export. Can any one help me with an expression to remove any line breaks that follow the "\" character in the data.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the "Replace" dialog, select "Extended" from the "Search Mode" section (bottom left of the dialog).
2. In the "Find what" box type: `\\\n`
3. In the "Replace with" box type: `\\`
4. Hit "Replace All"
5. Enjoy

[image: find and replace dialog]

Comment: or maybe repalce with "\r\"

Comment: Thank you Tom and Mehdi for your help. I have solved the problem with this data. It took notepad++ nearly 12 minutes to complete all the replaces but I now have a functional dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.
Did you try clicking on the "**Edit**" menu and "**Convert line breaks**" from the application "Notepad ++"?

[image]

Comment: Hi... I have v 6.1.2 of the application and there is no "Convert Line Breaks". There is a "Edit> Line Operations> Join Lines". Tried it took way too long. I need to replace all the line breaks only where they occur after the "\" character.

Comment: my version of "Notepad + +" is 6.2.3 and I'm having this option. Have you tried to update your notepad + +? Here is my screenshot  (I have the English version but I do not think this option is missing from yours)

Comment: I have just updated to v6.2.2 which has the EOL conversion (which I may have missed in the 6.1.x version), but it did not solve my problem. I think that I ma going to need to a Find and Replace with this. Thanks for your help.